# Getting error, when trying to get indexPath of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have added a UIButton in my UITableViewCell and in the action of that button, I have added the following code to get the indexPath of the cell. But it keeps returning the error- 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7cea3fc0'

Can anyone tell me what to do, here?

```
- (IBAction)navigateMap:(id)sender {
    __strong UIButton *button=(UIButton *) sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview;
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    //rest of the logic
}
```

FULL CODE

```
- (IBAction)navigateMap:(id)sender {
__strong UIButton *button=(UIButton *) sender;
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview;
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
CombinedStations *inButton=[[CombinedStations alloc] init];
inButton=[_finalStationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
_universalRegion->center.latitude=inButton.latitude;
_universalRegion->center.longitude=inButton.longitude;
NSString *launchUrl=@"";
launchUrl= [launchUrl stringByAppendingString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="];
NSString *tmpLat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", _universalRegion->center.latitude];
NSString *tmpLong = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", _universalRegion->center.longitude];
NSString *llat=[tmpLat stringByAppendingString:[@"," stringByAppendingString:tmpLong]];
launchUrl=[@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" stringByAppendingString:llat];
launchUrl=[launchUrl stringByAppendingString:[@"&saddr=" stringByAppendingString:@"Current Location"]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[launchUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, UITableViewCell does not implement that method.  Perhaps you should use a pointer to the UITableView instead.

Comment: Hint:  `navigateMap:` is in another class.  That class can store pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, This one will be very easy way to get the indexpath pf the table.

```
- (IBAction)navigateMap:(id)sender {

CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableViewName];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewName indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
}
```

Comment: Have you put NSLog and checked it? and sender is not nill right?

Comment: the app crashes immediately after 
`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewName indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
}`
and no, its not empty..table view & cell are not"nil"

Comment: what is your tablename?

Comment: tableView is the name used inside the action..you want the whole code?

Comment: alright..i will simply tell the context first. I have put a button that launches a "navigate in map" page. the cell loads an object for a "train Station" file.it contains its latitude and longitude, which i want to access, when the button i tapped

Comment: K instead of tableViewName in my code you changed it to tableView right? This tableView is created programatically or through IBOutlet?

Comment: eys ofcourse..i have added the full code to the question

Comment: like i said, the code doesn't get past the line
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
it crashes at that point

Comment: You are not clear you created tableview programatically or through IBoutlet?

Comment: I have created the tableview through IBOutlet

Comment: So you have named it as tableView right ? NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewName indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition]; so in this line put tableview instead of tableViewName.

Answer (score 1):

`button`'s superview is cell's `contentView`. Try getting superview of a button's superview:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = button.superview.superview;
```

IMHO this is a really bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get indexpath from the tableView. Simply create a delegate for that cell and fire it whenever the button is tapped.

Conform to the delegate within the owner of the tableView. Whenever you catch the callback ask to the tableview the indexPath of the incoming cell from the delegate.

```
- (void)cell:(SampleCell *)cell actionButtonTapped:(UIButton *)button
{
    self.currentIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```